# How to make `electric-pair-mode` always generate matching delimiters &parens in html/sgml/mhtml modes?

Tags: html, electric-pair-mode

When I type a single `{`, it will auto insert right `}`

But when I type a `{` again, it won't auto insert right `}`

[image]

How can I set up `electric-pair-mode` so that it always generates matching delimiters and parenthesis?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Drew I have added the obvious question. Hope that clears up your objection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that `electric-pair-mode` always pairs matching delimiters and parenthesis set `electric-pair-inhibit-predicate` to the function symbol `ignore`.

You can do this in a user-friendly way by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `electric-pair-inhibit-predicate` <kbd>RET</kbd>. You do not need to type very much if you exploit tab-completion.