# How to balance multiple pairs with electric-pair-mode

Tags: balanced-parentheses, electric-pair-mode

One such case is the double bracket in org mode: [[]]

If I type "[" twice I will get: [[]

The pair doesn't match!

There is a similar question with a different purpose.
[How to make `electric-pair-mode` always generate matching delimiters &parens in html/sgml/mhtml modes?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78595/how-to-make-electric-pair-mode-always-generate-matching-delimiters-parens-in)

I don't want to change electric-pair-inhibit-predicate, which also disables the ability to remove matching pair on deletion.

Comment: I just enabled `electric-pair-mode` in the \*scratch\* buffer in Emacs 29.3 and typed `[[` and ended up with my cursor in the middle of `[[]]`.  Likewise `[[[[[` gets me `[[[[[]]]]]`.  Which version of Emacs are you using?  Have you tested with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue in any version I tested back to 25.3.  I would expect you to see what I see in `emacs -Q` therefore I recommend you bisect your config (but maybe just starting with any obvious electric-pair-related customisations you can see) to figure out what's causing it.

Comment: It is caused by (setq electric-pair-inhibit-predicate 'electric-pair-conservative-inhibit)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is invalid

Comment: Rather than closing, just post the explanation as an Answer, which you can subsequently Accept.  That "conservative" option doesn't look like it's documented outside of lisp comments, so I see no issue with having a Q&A for it.